# MySql Switching Masters During Failover with log-slave-updates

Tags: mysql, replication, failover

I am still pretty newbie to mysql. This question is regarding promoting slave with option [--log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) to become a master.

The typical schema of promoting slave to master was described in [15.3.6 Switching Masters During Failover](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-solutions-switch.html). Here you can find very strict steps how to do it :

> Run your slaves with the --log-bin option and without --log-slave-updates. The reason for running the slave without --log-slave-updates is to prevent slaves from receiving updates twice in case you cause one of the slaves to become the new master.

Let's say I have the schema like the following (the image was taken from [15.3.5. Improving Replication Performance](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-solutions-performance.html)).

[image]

Where **Master 2** is actually a slave with [--log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) and bin-log enabled. I need to enable --log-slave-update in order to save bin-log from the **Master 1** to bin-log of **Master 2** and then transfer it to all slave. In case of failover I need promote **Master 2** to the role of **Master 1**. But there is a contradiction to the standard MySql failover schema I have --log-slave-updates enabled which can cause a problem.

In your opinion. What the action I should take in order to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning about `--log-slave-updates` will only apply if you had multiple intermediary 'Master/Slave' servers.

The warning is this (my emphasis):

> Then it will write updates that it receives from Master to its own binary log. **When Slave 2 changes from Master to Slave 1 as its master**, it may receive updates from Slave 1 that it has already received from Master

But in your scenario, `Slave 2` is not changing masters, it will still point to the same `Master 2` server it always was at.

So now, in case of `Master 1` failing, you will need to do two things:

- Make sure your applications point to `Master 2`
- Follow the instructions on [promoting one of the three slaves](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-solutions-switch.html) to be new `Master 2`
- make sure to enable `--log-slave-updates` on the new `Master 2`