# Safely promoting master to slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, failover

Previously I've asked the similar question [MySql Switching Masters During Failover with log-slave-updates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12224/mysql-switching-masters-during-failover-with-log-slave-updates).

Let's say this is our current replication

[image]

In addition, I have few application servers. Every app server connects to **Master 1** directly in order to INSERT and UPDATE and to Slave[1-3] in order to SELECT.

My question is how exactly can I promote **Master 2** to be a real and the only master. Importance notice that **Master 2** and all slaves below it are mysql 5.5 and **Master 1** is mysql 5.2

When I changed IP of **Master 1** to IP of **Master 2** in application settings and made deployment, there was a moment when I had UPDATE and INSERTS both on **Master 1** and **Master 2**, which caused "Duplicate entry ..." on **Master 2**. After that I rebuild the tree and run STOP SLAVE on **Master 2** few seconds before the deployment. Of course, I lost some data, that was inserted to **Master 1** and not replicated to **Master 2**.

So, what is the right way to do so without losting data.

In addition, I still don't understand what to run on **Master 2** after STOP SLAVE in order to reset "slave settings", it looks like I don't really have to do this, just STOP SLAVE and everything should be working, but just to keep the order I want to reset "slave settings".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you shifted the IP within your application, any DB Connections that were open at the moment were totally unaware of the move. A quick `netstat | grep -i mysql` would reveal that on **Master1**.

You would be better off doing the cutover of the IP as follows:

- On Master1

  - `FLUSH HOSTS;`
  - `service mysql stop`
- Change the IP in the App
- On all web servers, `service httpd restart`

In order to safeguard the app from having to edit it for the sake of assigning a new IP, try using a DB VIP instead.

For example:

- Master1 is 10.1.2.30
- Master2 is 10.1.2.40
- Use 10.1.2.70 as the DBVIP

Here is what you can setup

- On Master1, run `ip addr add 10.1.2.70/24 dev eth1`
- Use `10.1.2.70` in your app

Then, when it is time to cutover, do the following

- On Master1

  - `FLUSH HOSTS;`
  - `service mysql stop`
  - `ip addr del 10.1.2.70/24 dev eth1`
- On Master2

  - `ip addr add 10.1.2.70/24 dev eth1`
  - `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` and make sure all final SQL statements from Master1 executed
- On all web servers, `service httpd restart`

That way, a cutover would not involve editing any part of the app. Please notice that I did not mention running `STOP SLAVE` anywhere because this would allow any final SQL statements to flow over from Master1 to Master2 once mysql is stopped on Master1.